# how to match string value with database column?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have one table "TABLE_SUBJECT" And i pass "subject name" to DBHelper.java.
Then i need to compare subject name with Table Column "COLUMN_SUB_NAME" and return id of
That subject. i don't understand how to do this.please anybody provide me query
Which compare name and return column_id.
Any help s appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.rawQuery("select column_id from TABLE_SUBJECT where COLUMN_SUB_NAME='"+ subjectName +"'");
```

Comment: And how to get _id of that appropriate column?

Comment: db.rawQuery("select _id from TABLE_SUBJECT where COLUMN_SUB_NAME='"+ subjectName +"'");

Answer (score 1):

`Select column_id from your_table_name WHERE COLUMN_SUB_NAME='your_subject name';` that's the query You should try to get column_id related to that subject. 
for that you should use `db.rawQuery("Select column_id from your table_name WHERE COLUMN_SUB_NAME='your_subject name';");`